# How to bind a variable to a function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, bind

I am creating a function, that already has two arguments given. I want to bind a variable that would also get passed in.

```
this.listenTo(this.topView,this.directionChosen.bind('top');
this.listenTo(this.leftView,this.directionChosen.bind('left');
this.listenTo(this.rightView,this.directionChosen.bind('right');
this.listenTo(this.bottomView,this.directionChosen.bind('bottom');

directionChosen:function(item,move,direction) {

}
```

Is it possible to bind a variable/property and pass it in as direction in the function?

I have been looking around by doing this, but might not be doing it right.
Thanks

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JS but do you mean `directionChosen(0, 0, 'top')`? Or should the function always use `top`?

Comment: @MikeC that's valid. It looks like a custom prototype function delcaration

Comment: Sorry, I should have added the this.listenTo to show what exactly was being done.

Comment: There seems to be more things that you arent mentioning. Are you using Backbone? That is the only thing I am aware of that has a `listenTo` function.

Comment: @Jeff Yes I am using Backbone

Comment: @SterlingArcher Not by itself. The `directionChosen:function` section is accurate if it's being defined on an object but not if it directly follows a statement. Running that exact code will produce a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [doc for `.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), you can see that it takes one or more arguments.  The first argument is the `this` pointer you want set for the function call.  You must pass that as the first argument.  Other arguments after that are optional and will be the first arguments passed to your actual function.

Further (I can't quite tell what you want in your question), you must pass the actual argument you want passed, not a variable name.

So, the way you are doing it will not work.  You must pass the `this` value you want as the first argument and any additional arguments you pass will be sent to the function first, not last.

---

You can use a closure to solve your issue which is essentially the same thing that `.bind()` does, but in your own custom closure, you can do anything you want with the function arguments.

```
// method to call
directionChosen: function(item,move,direction) {

}

// code to call our method with custom arguments
var self = this;
this.listenTo(this.mainView, function(item, move) {
    self.directionChosen(item, move, 'top');
});
```

---

Or, if `top` is actually a variable name and you want that variable's value passed as the argument (unclear from your question which you want), it would look like this:

```
// code to call our method with custom arguments
var self = this;
this.listenTo(this.mainView, function(item, move) {
    self.directionChosen(item, move, top);
});
```

---

If you want to use this post-pend argument behavior a lot, you could create your own custom version of `.bind()` to do this for you.

```
Function.prototype.bindAfter = function(thisPtr /* one or more args */) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var self = this;
    args.shift();
    return function() {
        var newArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).concat(args);
        return self.apply(thisPtr, newArgs);
    }
};
```

You could then use `.bindAfter()` like this:

```
this.listenTo(this.topView,this.directionChosen.bindAfter(this, 'top'));
this.listenTo(this.leftView,this.directionChosen.bindAfter(this, 'left'));
this.listenTo(this.rightView,this.directionChosen.bindAfter(this, 'right'));
this.listenTo(this.bottomView,this.directionChosen.bindAfter(this, 'bottom'));
```

---

FYI, the brute force way of solving this is as follows:

```
var self = this;
this.listenTo(this.topView, function(item, move) {
    return self.directionChosen(item, move, 'top');
});
this.listenTo(this.leftView, function(item, move) {
    return self.directionChosen(item, move, 'left');
});
this.listenTo(this.rightView, function(item, move) {
    return self.directionChosen(item, move, 'right');
});
this.listenTo(this.bottomView, function(item, move) {
    return self.directionChosen(item, move, 'bottom');
});
```

Which is actually fewer new lines of code that creating `.bindAfter()`.

---

You could also make a helper function that as specific to just this one problem:

```
function callWithDirection(thisPtr, direction) {
    return function(item, move) {
        return thisPtr.directionChosen(item, move, direction)
    }
}
```

And, then you could use it like this:

```
this.listenTo(this.topView, callWithDirection(this, 'top'));
this.listenTo(this.leftView, callWithDirection(this, 'left'));
this.listenTo(this.rightView, callWithDirection(this, 'right'));
this.listenTo(this.bottomView, callWithDirection(this, 'bottom'));
```

Comment: I have multiple views, and I just want to add a property to be passed in by binding it to the function without having to create multiple functions just to say what the direction is

Comment: @user3000847 - as I've described, `.bind()` prepends the arguments.  That what it does.  It does not post-pend the argument like your example shows.  And, it requires the `this` pointer be passed.

Comment: is there any way to pass it in without .bind()?

Comment: @user3000847 - I'm trying to figure out if you're actually reading my answer or not.  I've provided you two wants to pass in the argument without `.bind()`.  I just added the second one.

Comment: Yes I have been reading your answers, I just feel that I'm not exactly understanding binding. I might be be in search of something/going around in the wrong way of things.

Comment: @user3000847 - then please try to ask a more specific question about what exactly you don't understand so we can explain it to you.

Comment: @user3000847 - I've added the brute force way of solving this too.

Comment: @user3000847 - I added one more option to make a special purpose helper function.

Answer (score 0):

Your most recent edit makes it much clearer what you're looking for.

Something like this should do.

```
directionChosen:function(item,move,direction) {

}

var directChosen = this.directionChosen;
function bindDirection(direction) {
    return function boundDirection(item, move){
        directionChosen.call(this, item, move, 'top');
    }
}

this.listenTo(this.mainView,bindDirection('top'));
this.listenTo(this.leftView,bindDirection('left'));
this.listenTo(this.rightView,bindDirection('right'));
this.listenTo(this.bottomView,bindDirection('bottom'));
```

---

ORIGINAL:

I've noticed a recent obsession with `Function.prototype.bind`. I find it's a little unnecessary. You can easily achieve a more readable, nearly identical result by defining a new function.

```
directChosen.bind(this, 'a', 'b');
```

is nearly identical to:

```
var context = this;
function(direction){
    directChosen.call(context, 'a', 'b', direction);
}
```

This way will at least provide you a meaningful function declaration when you're reading your code.

---

EDIT:

If you're looking for only `direction` to have the value `'top'`, just do:

```
function(item, move){
    directChosen.call(this, item, move, 'top');
}
```

---

If you want a `bindDirection` function, simply do something like:

```
function bindDirection(direction) {
    return function boundDirection(item, move){
        directChosen.call(this, item, move, 'top');
    }
}
```

Comment: `.apply()` takes an array for its second argument.  Perhaps you meant to use `.call()`.